# Transform all DataFrame Columns of a specific Type in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, julia-dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with `Int64` columns:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(a=1:3,b=4:6,c=["a","b","c"])

3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c
     │ Int64  Int64  String
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │     1      4    a
   2 │     2      5    b
   3 │     3      6    c
```

Now, I want to change the column types to `Float64`. I know that I can do something like...

```
using DataFramesMeta, Chain

@chain df begin
    @transform!(:a = Float64.(:a),
                :b = Float64.(:b))
end
```

or

```
df.a = Float64.(df.a)
df.b = Float64.(df.b)
```

But how can I change all columns of type `Int64` to `Float64`. Columns of other types should stay as they are.

(As you might guess from the example above I like the combination of `Chain` and `DataFramesMeta`, but of course all answers are more than welcome.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is (this updates your original data frame):

```
df .= Float64.(df)
```

With `transform!` you can alternatively do:

```
transform!(df, All() .=> ByRow(Float64), renamecols=false)
```

or you can also do:

```
mapcols!(ByRow(Float64), df)
```

(sorry - no DataFramesMeta.jl here yet - but things might change in the future)

---

If you want to change only e.g. columns that have `Int` type then do:

```
julia> transform!(df, names(df, Int) .=> ByRow(Float64), renamecols=false)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a        b        c
     │ Float64  Float64  String
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │     1.0      4.0  a
   2 │     2.0      5.0  b
   3 │     3.0      6.0  c
```

or

```
mapcols(df) do col
    eltype(col) === Int ? Float64.(col) : col
end
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the answer I'm looking for. I changed the question to make it more clear. My point is to change all the **columns that have a specific type** and leave columns alone which have a different type.

Comment: I have added an answer - use `names` as column selector in `transform!` or a more complex `mapcols` call.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (possibly less efficient):

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:3,b=4:6,c=["a","b","c"])
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c      
     │ Int64  Int64  String 
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │     1      4  a
   2 │     2      5  b
   3 │     3      6  c

julia> [df[!,col] = convert(Vector{Float64},df[!,col]) for col in names(df) if eltype(df[!,col]) <: Integer]
2-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
 [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

julia> df    
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a        b        c      
     │ Float64  Float64  String 
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │     1.0      4.0  a
   2 │     2.0      5.0  b
   3 │     3.0      6.0  c
```

(adapted from