# How to prevent Columns from being Decimals in DataFrames when retrieved from Postgres

Tags: dataframe, julia, libpq, dataframes.jl

I have a `DataFrame` `df` which I retrieved from a Postgres database as follows

```
using DataFrames, LibPQ

con = LibPQ.Connection(con_string)
result = execute(con, "SELECT * FROM [table]")
df = DataFrame(result)
close(con)
```

Sorry, I cannot make this reproducible.

Now, either `DataFrames` or `LibPQ` is turning `NUMERIC` Postgres columns into type `Decimals.Decimal`. This might be cool for being as accurate as possible, but it provides problems when I try to plot anything with these columns.

```
eltype.(eachcol(df))

5-element Vector{Union}:
 Union{Missing, String}
 Union{Missing, TimeZones.ZonedDateTime}
 Union{Missing, Int32}
 Union{Missing, Date}
 Union{Missing, Decimals.Decimal}
```

As very nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698199/transform-all-dataframe-columns-of-a-specific-type-in-julia) by Bogumił Kamiński I can change the columns of a specific type to some other type. The caveat is that I cannot even test whether a column is of type `Union{Missing, Decimals.Decimal}`, because the `Decimals` package is not loaded. OK, I thought, let's load the `Decimals` package then - but it doesn't work, because the package must be installed first...

Is there some other way to turn these columns into `Float64`s? Without having to install the entire package? I know that I could change the column types by using the column names, like

```
df.my_column = Float64.(df.my_column)
```

but I will not know the relevant column names in advance.

Comment: You can use `Union{Missing, AbstractFloat}` as type selector as `Decimal <: AbstractFloat`.

Comment: Dammit, you're right. Why didn't I think of that! Wanna make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Union{Missing, AbstractFloat}` as type selector as `Decimal <: AbstractFloat`.

Since `Union{Missing, AbstractFloat}` is not a concrete type you need to write `eltype(col) <: Union{Missing, AbstractFloat}` to check a subtyping condition.

---

By the way if you have LibPQ.jl installed then you also have access to Decimals.jl:

```
julia> LibPQ.Decimals.Decimal
Decimals.Decimal
```

Comment: Hm, I agreed so enthusiastically, but now that I tried it out I realized it does not actually work. Doing `mapcols(df) do col eltype(col) === Union{Missing, AbstractFloat} ? Float64.(col) : col end` does not transform any of the columns.

Comment: I have added an update `===` checks for exact equality of types.

Comment: OK, sorry for not getting it, but `==` doesn't work either.

Comment: You need to use `<:` not `==`. `<:` is doing subtyping test. (see an update in my answer)

Comment: I have added a comment how you can access Decimals.jl without adding it if you already have LibPQ.jl in your Project.toml.

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind how it maps each data type to each Julia type is in https://github.com/iamed2/LibPQ.jl/blob/master/src/parsing.jl. For instance there are the lines:

```
## integers
_DEFAULT_TYPE_MAP[:int2] = Int16
_DEFAULT_TYPE_MAP[:int4] = Int32
_DEFAULT_TYPE_MAP[:int8] = Int64
## floating point
_DEFAULT_TYPE_MAP[:float4] = Float32
_DEFAULT_TYPE_MAP[:float8] = Float64
## oid
_DEFAULT_TYPE_MAP[:oid] = Oid
## numeric
_DEFAULT_TYPE_MAP[:numeric] = Decimal
```

It does not appear that there is an easy way to overwrite the last default type map if you just want a Float64 rather than trying to deal with Decimals in return for additional accuracy at the 16th decimal place. But what you can do is:

- do `cast(whatever as float8)` in your postgres query for all of the numeric columns being output.
- Fork the package. Change this line and call your forked package rather than this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `identity` to properly type every column in `DataFrame`.

```
julia> df=DataFrame(A=Number[1,2],B=Union{Missing,AbstractFloat}[3,4])
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ A       B          
     │ Number  Abstract…? 
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │      1         3.0
   2 │      2         4.0

julia> identity.(df)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B       
     │ Int64  Float64 
─────┼────────────────
   1 │     1      3.0
   2 │     2      4.0
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in this case, as the goal is not just to get the narrowest type of values, but to convert them to a different type.

Comment: The question is to convert to `Float64`, but since it says "it provides problems when I try to plot anything with these columns.", I answered how to convert to a type that can be plotted. It is useful because it can be written short if the conversion to the narrowest type is sufficient instead of the conversion to a specific different type.